# XDB Disabled - Still getting tracking error in the logs

Tags: xdb

I have xdb disabled:

xdb.Enabled = false
xdb.Tracking.Enabled = false

Im still getting xdb related errors in the logs. Should this all be disabled (Sitecore 9.3):

```
7932 11:45:08 ERROR One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'sessionEnd:batch:starting' event.
Exception[1]: Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException 
Message[1]: The HTTP response was not successful: NotFound 
Source[1]: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web 
at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock(Func`1 taskFactory)
at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.Initialize(XmlNode configNode)
at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient(String clientConfigPath)
at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.BatchEnabledXdbRuntimeContext..ctor(IXdbContextFactory factory)
at Sitecore.Analytics.Events.BatchEventHandler.OnBatchStarting(Object sender, EventArgs args)
at Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result) 


77932 11:45:08 ERROR Cannot execute 'sessionEnd:batch:starting' event
   Exception: System.AggregateException
Message: One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'sessionEnd:batch:starting' event.
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
at Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result)
at Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters)
at Sitecore.Kernel.Web.SessionExpirationProcessor.TryRaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters)

Nested Exception

Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException
Message: The HTTP response was not successful: NotFound
Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web
at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock(Func`1 taskFactory)
at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.Initialize(XmlNode configNode)
at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient(String clientConfigPath)
at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.BatchEnabledXdbRuntimeContext..ctor(IXdbContextFactory factory)
at Sitecore.Analytics.Events.BatchEventHandler.OnBatchStarting(Object sender, EventArgs args)
at Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result)
```

Comment: Did you disable EXM as well by setting `exmEnabled:define=no` in the web.config?

Comment: I just checked... yes, I did.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with both xdb and xdb tracking disabled and it appears to be a sitecore 9.3 bug, so i got this workaround from sitecore support:

As a workaround please try to disable in the `\App_Config\Sitecore\Marketing.Tracking\Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config` file:

```
<events>
<event name="sessionEnd:batch:starting">
<handler type="Sitecore.Analytics.Events.BatchEventHandler, Sitecore.Analytics" method="OnBatchStarting" />
</event>
<event name="sessionEnd:batch:ended">
<handler type="Sitecore.Analytics.Events.BatchEventHandler, Sitecore.Analytics" method="OnBatchEnded" />
```